# Rename column in Pandas using index of column

Tags: python, pandas, rename, indexof

I have dataframe with two columns with identical names `Name_1` and `Name_1`. I cannot reproduce it here, since it came from `pd.read_csv`. I can find out index of each column, but I do not know how to rename column using index notation. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you not just do `df.columns = ['new_name1', 'new_name2']` or similar?

Comment: @EdChum Indeed, I can. Thank you for suggestion!

Comment: It just seems to me that for something this trivial you can just overwrite the columns directly. Also how did you end up with duplicate names? Really you should avoid this rather than try to fix it as a post-processing step

Comment: @EdChum. I totally agree about avoiding it, but it looks like side effect of pulling columns from SQL. I have to think about permanent fix.

Comment: You most certainly can reproduce part of it here. Please do not make our lives unnecessarily hard for trying to help you OP.

Comment: Using pandas.read_csv() should automatically handle columns with duplicate names as long as the mangle_dupe_cols is left at the default value of True. Are you using pandas 0.19.1? See the docs here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: @Alex I am working on reproducing the example. Data originally comes from SQL and then I store it in pickle and read from it. So my comment about csv is incorrect.